# Weeknumber of prior year

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

I work as a visiting nurse and have a scheduling Access 2016 database for my visit. One report uses the week number to group "whos due this week" for me to see. As it stands, some patients are WAY over due and their "next due" is a 2016 date making their "weeknumber" 51 or 52 or 53  OF 2016....uggh!

Is there a way in the grouping to set this 2016 date at the top of the report, since its and "old" date....2016.....while keeping the sorting for 2017? That is, show the overdue 2016 dates first, THEN show the 2017.

Source for the report is a query of a table. In this query I have:
NV_wknum: DatePart("ww",([Last S-Visit]+60))
as the weeknumber  (NV is next visit, which is 60 days after the last visit) for that specific entry.

The 2016 dates show at the end of the report since the weeknumbers are 51, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This function will return both year and week number for any given date according to the ISO 8601 standard:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekYearNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByRef intYear As Integer, _
  Optional ByRef bytWeek As Byte) _
  As String

' Calculates and returns year and week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' Optionally returns numeric year and week.
' 1998-2007, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53
  Const cbytMonthJanuary        As Byte = 1
  Const cbytMonthDecember       As Byte = 12
  Const cstrSeparatorYearWeek   As String = "W"

  Dim bytMonth                  As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  intYear = Year(datDate)
  bytMonth = Month(datDate)
  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(intYear, cbytMonthDecember, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000+ bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
  If bytMonth = cbytMonthJanuary Then
    If bytWeek >= cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear - 1 Then
      ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous year.
      intYear = intYear - 1
    End If
  ElseIf bytMonth = cbytMonthDecember Then
    If bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear Then
      ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next year.
      intYear = intYear + 1
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekYearNumber = CStr(intYear) & cstrSeparatorYearWeek & Format(bytWeek, "00")

End Function
```

You may use a different week system. Then just - in your report - first sort on

```
Year(DateAdd("d",60,[Last S-Visit]))
```

then on

```
DatePart("ww",DateAdd("d",60,[Last S-Visit]))
```

If 60 days means 2 months, then add months:

```
Year(DateAdd("m",2,[Last S-Visit]))
```

then on:

```
DatePart("ww",DateAdd("m",2,[Last S-Visit]))
```

Remember to remove all sorting from the query driving the report; sorting must be specified in the report itself.